# Customizing the Facebook view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I need the lightblue bar to scroll up (hide) and display the Facebook bar. For example look at this [image](http://socialmediaseo.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/iphone-facebook-1.jpg).

I need the light blue bar (which contains the search bar, refresh button) to be scrolled up, so it hides and displays from the Dark Blue Facebook bar as shown in this [image](http://media.techeblog.com/images/iphonefacebook.jpg).

I have seen this in many applications but, how can i implement it in my application programatically ?

Comment: Hi Sharon, is this for a web app or an objective-c app? How are you loading the view? Looks like safari rather than a UIWebView?

Comment: This is an iPhone/obj-C application. It is through a UIWebview that it gets loaded

Comment: Your question probably needs more details then, as the address&search bar shown in your example are not created by UIWebView. If you're referring to removing the navigation bar in a UINavigationController hierarchy then try the answer I'm about to post below.

Comment: Sorry its Safari, not UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to control safari from your app, and since Facebook serves the HTML there's no way to alter that either. So to achieve what you're looking for you could create your own UIWebView and present it modally instead. The issue you'll have here, though, is that you won't have access to the users cookies, so they'll have to log in to Facebook again.